# Geo coordinates for a polygon over Germany (or any other region)

Tags: java, geolocation, coordinates, point-in-polygon

I am using java. I want to check wether or not some location lies in germany (it is an application for a company, and its trucks aren't allowed to cross borders).

Now I know, that one can only approximate this, but thats okay, since I mainly want to check for typos in longitude and latitude (e.g. 25.123 instead of 52.123).

So far I came across the point in polygon problem, which seems to fit my needs. Is there like a standard for geo-polygons over regions? (**). Or do I have to do it by myself?

(**) This seems like a dumb question. However it would offer transparency to my customer and I wouldn't be to blame if my polygon is 1 meter to small.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are asking for "*standard for geo-polygons over regions*". In Germany there is the "[Digitales Landschaftsmodell](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digitales_Landschaftsmodell)" (DLM) and "[Digitales Geländemodell](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digitales_H%C3%B6henmodell)" (DGM).

There is also a public [service](http://www.geodatenzentrum.de) where different [spatial data](http://www.geodatenzentrum.de/geodaten/gdz_rahmen.gdz_div?gdz_spr=deu&gdz_akt_zeile=5&gdz_anz_zeile=1&gdz_unt_zeile=3&gdz_user_id=0) can be downloaded.

So hopefully using offical standards and data will meet the customer's requirements.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I meant with standard. However it seems to me, that they work with grids. I would have to eliminate points inside the grid itself. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @DavidLehnherr There is also a version called XYZ listing the positions by coordinates (lng/lat) and elevation.

Comment: Yes I saw this. However for the point in polygon problem I need to specify a polygon (so its edges). In order to do so, I have to find the geo coordinates of the german border. Since this is a grid, I would have to extract those points.

Comment: Yes, you would have to determine the outer shape representing the border. This wiould be the polygon to test if a point is in. Since you have the datta this is no big deal and has to be done only once .... assuming the borders doesn't change ;)

Comment: Sure, you are right, now I see it. There is also an "algorithm-less" version. If we use Graphhopper for routing (with a simple Germany osm file), we will never cross borders. (But my customer would have to double check, that he doesn't do any typos). Thanks, this answered my question!

Comment: Glad i could help you as I faced a similar task.

Answer (score 0):

You  may easily get the data from [this site](https://gadm.org/download_country_v3.html), Germany looks precise enough:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, thats what I am looking for. The next big task will be to access the data within my code. Do you know how to do it in java? - The GDAL/OGR doc examples are mainly in C/C++.

Answer (score 0):

**GeometryFactory** from **com.vividsolutions.jts.geom** contains a method that checks if a gps coodiantes are inside a polygon.
If you have your area polygon figured out, maybe all you need is to reconstruct your polygon using the library and check if your coordinates are inside your polygon.
This is not a perfect example but you can tweak it to your likeing.

```
private com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.GeometryFactory geometryFactory;

public boolean isCoordinatesInsidePolygon(double lat, double lng, MyPolygon myPolygon) {
            final Polygon area =geometryFactory.createPolygon(myPolygon.getCoordinates());
            final Point point = geometryFactory.createPoint(new Coordinate(lat, lng));
            return area.covers(point);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This is definitely cleaner than my implementation :)